# Prove that a compact subset of a normed vector space is closed and bounded - Proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

Prove that a compact subset, $S$,  of a normed vector space, $V$, is closed and bounded.

**Attempt:**

1) Showing $S$ is closed

To show $S$ is closed we have to show that $S$ contains all of its limit points.

PF: Suppose there exists a sequence $\{s_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in S$ such that $s_n \rightarrow s$. Where $s$ is a limit point of the set $S$. I will show that $s \in S$.

Since $s \in V$ and we assumed $s_n$ converges this means $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \|s_n - s \| \rightarrow 0$$

Since $S$ is compact this means every sequence $s_n \in S$ has a subsequence $s_{n_{k}}$ that converges to a point $d \in S$. This also means $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|s_{n_{k}} - d\| \rightarrow 0$$

Consider $\|s-d\|$:

$$\|s-d\| = \|s- s_{n_{k}} + s_{n_{k}} - d\| \leq \|s- s_{n_{k}}\| + \|s_{n_{k}} - d\| $$

Since $s_n \rightarrow s$ all subsequences also converge to $s$. This means $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\|s- s_{n_{k}}\| \rightarrow 0$. As well We have also established that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|s_{n_{k}} - d\| \rightarrow 0$.

Therefore: $$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|s-d\| = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|s- s_{n_{k}} + s_{n_{k}} - d\| \leq \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|s- s_{n_{k}}\| + \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|s_{n_{k}} - d\| = 0 $$

So $s = d \in S$. Therfore $S$ is closed.

2) Showing $S$ is bounded.

To show $S$ is bounded, I want to show that for all $s \in S$ there exists $M$ such that $|s| \leq M$.

PF: Towards contradiction suppose $S$ was unbounded. given that $S$ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence $s_{n_{k}}$ that converges to a value $s$ in $S$.  Therefore: $$|s| = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\|s_{n_{k}}\| \geq \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} = +\infty $$.

This is not possible thus a contradiction.

**Comment:** For showing closed I know that is the right procedure, but I feel I may have messed up in expressing the convergence of the two sequences using $k$. Feedback about the proof?

Comment: "for all $s\in S$ there exists $M$ so $|s|\le M$" is true for _any_  set. Saying $S$ is bounded means there exists $M$ so $|s|\le M$ for all $s\in S$.

Comment: The proof of the second part makes no sense. I think you just left out the sentence where you say what $s_n$ is...

Comment: Suppose that $S$ is unbounded. Then $A_n = S\cap B(0, n)^c$ is a decreasing sequence of non-empty compact sets with empty intersection, contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively. Suppose that $S$ is unbounded, there exist a sequence $s_n$ such that $||s_n|| \to \infty$ when $n\to \infty$. Since $S$ is compact, there exists its convergent subsequence $n_k$. But convergent sequences are bounded, $s_{n_k}$ isn't bounded.

Comment: Even different approach. $S\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B(0, n) = V$. We can take a finite subcover, so $S\subset B(0, m)$ for some $m\geq 1$, as desired.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, specifically that $s_n$ is a sequence that does not have a convergent subsequence?.....

Comment: That's the _conclusion_, not the defintion of $s_n$. The argument is "If $S$is unbounded choose $s_n$ such that ... . Then ???, so $s_n$ hhas no convergent subsequence." The "..." is missing.

Comment: If you sayy "let $s_n$ be a sequence wiith nno convergent subsequence" you're assumming what you have to prove.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I see what you're getting at. Now I have to figure out what the ..... actually is.

Comment: WHat does it _mean_ to say $S$ iis unbounded?

Comment: If $S$ is unbounded, by just negating the definition: for all $M$, there  exists $s \in S$ s.t. $|s| \geq M$.

Comment: Right. So there exists a sequence $s_n$ with...

Comment: I can't stand it. If $S$ is unbounded tthere exists $(s_n)\subset S$ with $||s_n||\ge n$. Hence $||s_n||\to\infty$. So any subsequence has $||s_{n_j}||\to\infty$, hence $(s_{n_j})$ iis nnot convergent. Merry Christmas.

Comment: Sorry for not putting it together quicker @DavidC.Ullrich, I was trying to figure it out without having to refer to my textbook.